# get unused security list from all regions thru boto3

Tags: boto3, aws-security-group

i m trying to get unused SG from all regions but its not working .

i tried below code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
regions = ec2.describe_regions().get('Regions',[])
for region in regions:
  reg=region['RegionName']

sgs = list(ec2.security_groups.all())
insts = list(ec2.instances.all())

all_sgs = set([sg.group_name for sg in sgs])
all_inst_sgs = set([sg['GroupName'] for inst in insts for sg in inst.security_groups])
unused_sgs = all_sgs - all_inst_sgs

print 'Total SGs:', len(all_sgs)
print 'SGS attached to instances:', len(all_inst_sgs)
print 'Orphaned SGs:', len(unused_sgs)
print 'Unattached SG names:', unused_sgs
```

Comment: You extract the region but not using it anywhere.  To switch region in the code, you need to use boto3.session

Answer (score 0):

describe_regions is a function of the ec2 client, not the ec2 resource.  Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
regions = ec2.describe_regions().get('Regions',[])
for region in regions:
  reg=region['RegionName']
```

However you're not using the region name in any way.  The following code iterates across the regions, sets up a new ec2 resource in each region, and repeats your scans.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import boto3


ec2Client = boto3.client('ec2')
regions = ec2Client.describe_regions().get('Regions',[])
for region in regions:
    reg=region['RegionName']
    print ('Checking region {}'.format(reg))

    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name=reg)

    sgs = list(ec2.security_groups.all())
    insts = list(ec2.instances.all())

    all_sgs = set([sg.group_name for sg in sgs])
    all_inst_sgs = set([sg['GroupName'] for inst in insts for sg in inst.security_groups])
    unused_sgs = all_sgs - all_inst_sgs

    print ('    Total SGs:', len(all_sgs))
    print ('    SGS attached to instances:', len(all_inst_sgs))
    print ('    Orphaned SGs:', len(unused_sgs))
    print ('    Unattached SG names:', unused_sgs)
```

While testing I found I have a lot of unused SGs, thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much its working for me as expected and I got the point where i was wrong Thanks again

Comment: hey its working as expected but i need to find unused SGs on basis of EC2,RDS,ELB all for now i am checking only those security group which are not attached to EC2 but i need the list of all SGs which are not attached to any of EC2,RDS,ELB

Comment: response = boto3.client('rds').describe_db_security_groups()

Comment: response = boto3.client('elb').describe_load_balancers()

Comment: Thanks , how can I put my output in one csv file please advise me ?

Comment: I am new in boto3 can you please tell me how can i implement RDS & ELB code in above code